# Powershell, VS2019, db migrations: 'Drop-Database' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

Whatever command I use I get the error:

> drop-database : The term 'drop-database' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable --> complete msg see image!

[image]

-Environment: VS2019

.…\CU21 contains the project (.sln)

- which component am I missing, needs updating?
- what do I do wrong?

Comment: further tests showed:
when using "dotnet ef database drop" in  VS Code; DB is dropped !

it seems my VS2019 has an issue
PS: via VS installer I added the latest updates!

Drop-Database in VS2019 powershell original issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some trial/error using update-database I got below msg:

PM> update-database
The EF Core tools version '2.1.1-rtm-30846' is older than that of the runtime '2.1.11-servicing-32099'. **Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes.**

After doing the core tools update - all was ok!